# Show message on screen after starting app and going into it's url

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an app with .net as backend and Angular as frontend. The backend app doesn't have any of it's own frontend code. I want it to show a message on screen when i go to localhost:5001. This is to be sure the app is running without issues.

I had an old web app that ran on .net core 2.2, and inside Startup.cs there was this:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(env.ContentRootPath);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles()
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseMvc()
            .Run(async (context) =>
            {   
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Worker Process Name : API") ;
            });
```

When i run this app and go to localhost:5001 it shows this:
[image: text printed on screen in localhost:5001]

Now, my latest app runs on .net 6,there is no Startup.cs anymore.
This is how the app is built on Program.cs (Note, this is simplyfied to just show the most critical stuff):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);   
builder.Services.AddMvc();   
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseDefaultFiles().UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

When i run this if i again go to localhost:5001 i get a 404 error. The app works correctly, that's not an issue.

Now my question is: How can i make the newer app show a message on screen when i go to localhost:5001 like the old one did?

I tried adding the same code from the old .net core 2.2 app:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run(async (context) =>
     {
         await context.Response.WriteAsync("Worker Process Name : API"
         );
     });
```

But that doesn't work, in fact, the whole app doesn't work anymore if i try this.

If anyone knows a way to make it show something on screen again please tell me. If that's not possible anymore then printing something on the browser's console could be a solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated

Simply print the words is not correct logically. The endpoint hits correctly will print the word.

---

The `app.Run()` method is typically used to run the application and listen for incoming HTTP requests, not to add additional middleware as you did in the .NET Core 2.2 example. In the minimal app , the `endpoints.MapControllers()` may not be so necessary, after my testing, it works.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseDefaultFiles().UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapGet("/", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Worker Process Name : API");
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

[image]